# Eclipse slow text file opening

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have had this before and after switching computers and a long time of happy developing, I'm having it again: Eclipse taking extremely long to open simple text files.

What's happening, what's changed is:

- Tomcat now requires frequent restarts / reloads even changing Javascript files
- text files take at least 30 seconds to open

My environment is:

- Mac OS Maverick
- STS 3.4.0
- Sysdeo Tomcat
- Maven project nature
- AspectJ capability
- Android development tools
- Gradle IDE

I realize that reinstalling Eclipse/STS would be an option, but in stead of taken half a day to get it just right again, I would prefer to just fix the problem. Any ideas?

Is there any way to trace where eclipse is spending its time, some kind of high level debug output?

Comment: Which Eclipse editor is responsible for handling text files ? You can see that in file associations.

Comment: I recently installed LESS for Eclipse. I just uninstalled and things *seem* better. The Eclipse editor I'm using is Javascript editor and Default editor

Comment: You may also disable spell checking as it consumes some resources.

Comment: Ok, uninstalling LESS did not in fact resolve the issue. @Christophe: but it was working fine before. Why would it "suddenly" change

Comment: It is hard to tell what plugin causes a slowdown as I do not have those, I just wanted to point out that you can save some resources by disabling the spell checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after removing *.js from the file associations, the problem seemed to go away. After that I readded it again and everything was good again. Thanks @Cristophe for pointing me in the right direction